# Base64 library for 0.8.0 solidity compiler?

Tags: solidity

I am using this library for 0.5.0 solidity contracts. Now I need it for 0.8.0.
Do you know an alternative for it? It returns errors that I don't know to solve.

https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/solidity-jwt/blob/master/contracts/Base64.sol

Comment: The errors are produced because prior to version `0.8.0`, `byte` used to be an alias for `bytes1`. Change that and the code should work.

Answer (score 1):

I found an alternative for solidity 0.8.0 :

https://github.com/BlockChainCaffe/Base64.sol/blob/main/contracts/base64.sol

Answer (score 0):

As of May 2023, OpenZeppelin v4.9 now comes with support for Solidity v0.8:

https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/release-v4.9/contracts/utils/Base64.sol

Additionally, there is also Solady now, which offers support for both encoding and decoding Base64 strings in Solidity:

https://github.com/Vectorized/solady/blob/8d868a936ec1a45be294e26de1a64ebfb73c6c20/src/utils/Base64.sol